How can I avoid a read error from the Cloud Storage emulator?
I have closed access for some rules, to authorise only Firebase Admin SDK from a Cloud Functions, to read or write a file in Cloud Storage.
storage.rules content:
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Firebase Admin SDK only
    match /{file=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}

The rule above causes the following read error when using the emulator:
ApiError: Permission denied. No READ permission.

If I change this rule from false to true, I no longer have the read error using the Cloud Storage emulator:
// Firebase Admin SDK only
match /{file=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}

Closed access rules work in production on Cloud Storage, which means that the emulator interprets rules differently.
Do you have a solution? Possibly a patch?

If you believe there is a bug in the emulator, Stack Overflow is highly unlikely to give you an answer.  You should post your findings on GitHub so that Firebase staff can have a more direct record of the problem and work with you to address it.

Thanks. I didn't immediately think of GitHub. I'll post an issue.

firebase-tools issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/7946

A member of the firebase-tools team has successfully reproduced the bug.
To track the resolution of the bug:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/7946
